# Prevenir ataques SQL via $_POST x-editable

Tags: php, sql, twitter-bootstrap, pdo

Existe alguma maneira de prevenir ataques SQL no `$_POST`, sendo que **ele recebe todo tipo de valor**, url, nome, data e alguns caracteres especiais.

Estou usando o plugin **[x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html)** (antigo Bootstrap Editable).

```
    include_once("connection.php");
    try { 
        $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", "$user", "$password");
    }catch(PDOException $e_msg) {
        echo $e_msg->getMessage();
    }

    $pk = $_POST['pk'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $value = $_POST['value'];

    $sql = "UPDATE confvar1 ".
    "SET $name='$value' ".
    "WHERE vid_name_id = '$pk'";

    $STH = $DBH->exec($sql);
```

A página *index.php* envia via `post`.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
              $('#content a').editable({
                ajaxOptions : {
                    type : 'post'
                },
                 url: 'post.php'
              });
    });
```

*Qualquer otimização é bem vinda.*